# Removing random element from an array /Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I googled my question but found no answer, thank you in advance for help. The thing is, I have some code that works ok, but I would like to improve it:

```
function go(times) {
    function pick(n) {
        return n[Math.floor(Math.random() * n.length)];
    }

    var body = ["face", "nose", "hair", "smile"];
    var adj = ["amazing", "nice", "beautiful", "perfect"];
    var word = ["great", "innocent", "glowing", "adorable"];

    var str = "Your " + pick(body) + " looks " + pick(adj) + " and " + pick(word) + "!";
    if (times > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            str = str + " And " + go().toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

When the random word is picked, it should be removed from an array so there won't be any repeation. I can handle it with splice function if I know exact index of element, but when it's random it doesn't work how I want it to.

Comment: make pick() return the index not the value, then you can read/delete body[index].

Comment: And also maybe use recursion instead of for loop.

Comment: In you current solution can you tell me how are you removing the random elements ? Because i could not figure that out .

Comment: @ramasCoder it depends on which solution you are talking about. Currently I use the code that Lucounu proposed, look below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add a function to all arrays to return a random value and/or remove one randomly.

```
// After this, you can call.getRandomValue() on any array!
Array.prototype.getRandomValue = function(removeItem) {
    if (this.length < 1) throw "Cannot get random value from zero-length array";
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
    var randomValue = this[randomIndex];
    if (removeItem)
        this.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    return randomValue;
};

function constructDescription(sentenceCount) {
    var body = ["face", "nose", "hair", "smile"];
    var adj = ["amazing", "nice", "beautiful", "perfect"];
    var word = ["great", "innocent", "glowing", "adorable"];    

    var description = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < sentenceCount; i++) {
      if (body.length > 0 && adj.length > 0 && word.length > 0) {
        description += (description.length > 0) ? " And your " : "Your ";
        description += body.getRandomValue(true) + " looks " + adj.getRandomValue(true) + " and " + word.getRandomValue(true) + "!"         
      }    
    }

    return description;
}
```

**[Try it out with a Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/qwx7cr4f/)**

Comment: That is impressive, I wasn't sure to ask my question here, but now I am glad I did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine your splice and your randomizer. example:

```
function go(times) {

    var body = ["face", "nose", "hair", "smile"];
    var adj = ["amazing", "nice", "beautiful", "perfect"];
    var word = ["great", "innocent", "glowing", "adorable"];

    function pick(n) {
        return n.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * n.length), 1);
    }

    var str = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        str += (i > 0 ? " And your ":"Your ") + pick(body) + " looks " + pick(adj) + " and " + pick(word) + "!";
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different function instead of calling `go()` recursively in the loop. By calling `go()` for each phrase you initialize the original arrays each time. Then do the splicing in `pick()`

```js
function go(times) {
  var body = ["face", "nose", "hair", "smile"];
  var adj = ["amazing", "nice", "beautiful", "perfect"];
  var word = ["great", "innocent", "glowing", "adorable"];
  var str = ''

  function pick(n) {
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * n.length);
    var str = n[idx];
    n.splice(idx, 1)
    return str;
  }

  function getPhrase(i) {
    var phrase =  pick(body) + " looks " + pick(adj) + " and " + pick(word) + "!";
    return i == 0 ? "Your " + phrase : " And your " + phrase;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    str += getPhrase(i);
  }


  return str;
}

document.body.innerHTML = go(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

@lucounu solution is absolutely spot on.

In case if you just wanted to improve upon your initial solution , you could have done the following :

```
    var body = ["face", "nose", "hair", "smile"];
    var adj = ["amazing", "nice", "beautiful", "perfect"];
    var word = ["great", "innocent", "glowing", "adorable"];

    function go(times) {

    function pick(n) {
        var index =  Math.floor(Math.random() * n.length)
        var randomString  = n[index];
        n.splice(index,1);
        return randomString;
    }

    var str = "Your " + pick(body) + " looks " + pick(adj) + " and " + pick(word) + "!";

    if (times > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            str = str + " And " + go().toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    return str;
}

console.log(go(2));
```

Comment: neat and simple, I like it :)

Answer (score -2):

**Give it a try**

```
var data = ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker", "beaker-2", "scientist", "cell", "atom"];

    while (data.length) {
        document.write(data.splice(data.length * Math.random() | 0, 1)[0] + '<br>');
    }
```

Comment: Function is called recursively so all the arrays are declared again each time. This alone won't help. Try it yourself

Comment: Why the use of `document.write()` You have basically rewritten the method rather than fixing the one in question...